# Abundance of Cash - What should I do?

Tags: investing, retirement, savings

There seems to be a glut of information and I don't know where to start.

My situation is:

- No debt/kids
- Own Home and Vehicles
- Have a years worth of living expenses in my savings/checking
- Max out my 401k and Roth IRA
- Have a lot of money in a money market
- Save about 5k/month

I feel like I should be doing something better than a money market.  And I guess I should have a traditional IRA too?  Also, I have a broker managing my Roth IRA and hes lost money over the past 3 years.

I want some advice on what to do with the money I save, money in the money market and where to start my education on managing my excess money and turning it into residual income so that I can retire early.

Comment: The maximum IRA contribution for each year is fixed by law, but you can choose how much of that you want to contribute to a Roth IRA and how much to a Traditional IRA. If you are maxing out your Roth IRA as you say you are doing, you cannot contribute to a Traditional IRA too.

Comment: if you have a 401k at work it is possible that a regular ira is not a possibility.  http://www.irs.gov/retirement/participant/article/0,,id=202516,00.html shows the limits if you are covered by a retirement plan at work

Comment: You could take a trip to Vegas ;)

Comment: Describe your tolerance for risk.

Comment: Also, when you say you "own home and vehicles" you mean you have no debt, or you have them?

Comment: If it's true that your Roth IRA has lost money over the last three calendar years, I would look for a new manager. Since March 2009, the S&P 500 is up approximately 100%, and other assets like bonds and commodities are also up significantly. It's hard for me to imagine how one could have been invested to have lost money over that period.

Comment: There are a lot of investments available depending upon your interests, skills, and risk tolerance. You could invest in securities in a non-tax-sheltered brokerage account, invest in real estate, or start a business. You are in a very favorable situation that I think a lot of people would envy. :)

Comment: How close are you to when you want to retire? Are you 30 wanting to retire at 50, or are you 50 and want to retire at 55?

Comment: Im 28, my tolerance for risk is pretty high, my wife's is the complete opposite. I like the idea of real estate, but it seems outside my bubble of knowledge (I am a software developer).  @MrChrister I mean no debt. I also have them =)

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I'm 28 and I don't really want to retire ever, I just want enough residual income that I don't have to work a 40 hour/week or worse, spend 80hr/week stressing out over my own consulting business.

Comment: Man, I wish I had these problems! ;)

Answer (score 3):

People have asked a lot of good questions about your broader situation, tolerance for risk, etc, but I'm going to say the one-size-fits-most answer is: split some of your monthly savings (half?) into the [VEU Vanguard FTSE All-World ex-US ETF](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=0991&FundIntExt=INT) and some into [VTI Vanguard Total Stock Market ETF](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=0970&FundIntExt=INT).

This can be as automatic and hassle-free as the money market deposit and gives a possibility of getting a better return, with low costs and low avoidable risk.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few different types of investments you could do.

- As poolie mentioned, you could split your money between the Vanguard All World ex-US and Vanguard Total Stock Market index. A similar approach would be to invest in the [Vanguard Total World Stock ETF](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=3141&FundIntExt=INT). You wouldn't have to track separate fund performances, at the downside of not being able to allocate differential amounts to the US and non-US markets (Vanguard will allocate them by market cap).
- You could consider investing in country-specific broad market indices like the S&P 500 and FTSE 100. While not as diversified as the world indices, they are more correlated with the country's economic outlook.
- Other common investing paradigms are investing in companies which have historically paid out high dividends and companies that are under-valued by the market but have good prospects for future growth. This gets in the domain of value investing, which an entire field by itself.

Like Andrew mentioned, investing in a mutual fund is hassle-free. However, mutual fees/commissions and taxes can be higher (somewhere in the range 1%-5%) than index funds/ETF expense ratios (typically <0.50%), so they would have to outperform the market by a bit to break-even.

There are quite a few good books out there to read up about investing. I'd recommend [The Intelligent Investor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060555661) and [Millionaire Teacher](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470830069) to understand the basics of long-term investing, but of course, there are many other equally good books too.

Answer (score 1):

Since your 401k/IRA are maxed out and you don't need a 529 for kids, the next step is a plain ol' "Taxable account." The easiest and most hassle-free would be automatic contributions into a Mutual Fund.

Building on poolie's answer, I think mutual funds are much more automatic/hassle-free than ETFs, so in your case (and with your savings rate), just invest in the Investor (or Admiral) shares of VEU and VTI.

Other hassle-free options include I-Bonds ($5k/year), and 5-year CDs.